# I don't know what's going wrong with this code?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc

I am writing a simple code which accepts a string from the user of any length and just displays it. But my code is not doing it correctly as it accepts the string but not prints it correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    int i,len;
    static int n=5;
    char a[20];
    char **s;
    s=malloc(5*sizeof(char));
    char *p;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",a);
        if(*a=='1')                   /*to exit from loop*/
        {
            break;
        }
        len=strlen(a);
        p=malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(p,a);
        s[i]=p;
        if(i==n-1)
        {
            s=realloc(s,(5+i*5)*sizeof(char));
            n=5+i;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",s[i]);
    }
    free(p);
    p=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `I am writing a simple code which accepts a string from the user of any length and just displays it.`...to  much work you're doing here...

Comment: *"I don't know what's going wrong with this code?"* - A mere question mark doesn't make that sentence into a question. Read [this post about debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You want to `accepts a string from the user of any length` but you only have an array of 19 characters

Comment: `fgets` is far more conducive to what you are doing here than `scanf` (and that is generally the case any time user-input is involved)

Comment: One point subtracted for meaningless question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues, but at first look, the most prominent one is,

```
  s=malloc(5*sizeof(char));
```

is wrong. `s` is of type `char **`, so you'd need to allocate memory worth of `char *` there. In other words, you expect `s` to point to a `char *` element, so, you need to allocate memory accordingly.

To avoid *these* sort of mistakes, never rely on *hardcoded* data types, rather, use the form

```
 s = malloc( 5 * sizeof *s);  // same as s=malloc( 5 * sizeof (*s))
```

where, the size oid essentially determined from the type of the variable. Two advantages

- You avoid mistakes like above.
- The code becomes more resilient, you don;t need to change the `malloc()` statement in case you choose to change the data type

That said, `scanf("%s",a);` is also potentially dangerous and cause buffer overflow by longer-than-expected-input. You should always limit the input scanning length, using the maximum field width, like

```
scanf("%19s",a);  // a is array of dimension 20, one for terminating null
```

---

That said, to advice about the logic, when you don't know or don't dictate the length of the input string beforehand, you cannot use a *string* type to *scan* the input. The basic way of getting this done would be

1. Allocate a moderate length buffer, dynamically, using allocator functions like `malloc()`.
2. Keep reading the input stream one by one, `fgetc()` or alike.
3. If the read is complete (for example, return of `EOF`), you've read the complete input.
4. If the allocated memory has run out, re-allocate the original buffer and continue to step 3.

and, don't forget to `free()` the memory.

Otherwise, you may use `fgets()` to read chunks of memory and keep realloacting as mentioned above.